# Combine multiple TIFF Files into one

Tags: qgis, raster, geotiff-tiff, merge, mosaic

I have brought in multiple TIFF (raster) files into QGIS and want to combine them into one file.  I tried this by going to Raster> Misc.> Merge.  When doing this the output file comes out as gray and black and I want to keep the colors of my TIFF files.

[image: Colour topographic TIFF image of Norwich UK]

Comment: have you tried using `gdal_merge.py` from the command line?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to use `Merge tool` from `Processing toolbox -> GDAL/OGR -> Miscellaneous -> Merge`  it has the option to `Grab pseudocolor table from first layer` that you need to check, as you can see below:

[image]

Do not forget to choose a proper `Output raster type` that match the raster type of the input data, or any type that is close to input raster data.

For example, I have two topographic map sheets with `8 bit unsigned integer`, but I don't have the same pixel type, so I chose `UInt16` which is `16 bit unsigned integer`.

Input:

[image]

Here is the output after running the Merge tool:

[image]

Comment: Thank You, it worked.  Now how can I, if possible, remove that black line in between the images I merge.

Comment: Also, with my TIFFs when I merge they change color to grayscale.  Not sure why.

Comment: @Jhunt9 make sure that pixel type in settings in the merge tool matches input raster pixel type.

Comment: How do I check what raster pixel type my inputs are?  Are you talking about the output raster type?  The one that defaults to Float32?

Comment: Go to the right-click the raster layer in the table of content -> layer properties -> metadata and scroll down until you see pixel type and check what type from there.

Comment: That works!  Thank you.  Any clue on how to remove the lines I am getting in between them now?

Comment: You may need to set the -n nodata_value OR -a_nodata output_nodata_value, I am not sure. Please check the help: http://www.gdal.org/gdal_merge.html

Answer (score 1):

Try the Clipper tool.  Raster->Extraction->Clipper

Set the extent to cover the area you want to combine.

Comment: I can only select one input file when I do this and I want to select all of the files and combine them together.

Comment: Yes that is correct.  I apparently misread your question.